# Spigot cannot be resolved to a module in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I'm new to programming and I'm not sure how to rectify this issue in eclipse.

No matter what I try I'm not able to get rid of this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[module-info.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttUVM.png)

Comment: Would be good to see what you tried. Also, do you have a module-info.java file? It would be good to see that as well. Lastly, have you put a reference to the spigot jar on the module path in your Build Configurations?

Comment: Use ctrl + t, a small window will be displayed, type JavaPlugin to check it exists in your .jar file. The package name could be wrong.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a 'modular' project for a Minecraft plugin - so delete the 'module-info.java' file to make the project non-modular.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Spigot and deleting everything I wrote. I do have a module-info.java file. I'll attach a screenshot of it. As for the module name, I checked it and it matches. Lastly, I did put a reference to spigot on the module path.

Comment: Deleting the module-info.java file changed "spigot cannot be resolved to a module" to "JavaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type" and The type org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin is not accessible"

Comment: Out of my depth here. Is spigot a server or a library? What is your goal, stepping back to a more general picture? Also, it indeed might require that you run the project via Java 8. If so, you can try setting that in the properties/JavaCompiler/CompilerComplianceLevel, or it might require downloading Java 8 (OpenJDK 8). Hopefully someone who has actually used this software will see your post, or try asking at a more gaming oriented site like jvm-gaming.org.

Comment: It's a library, my goal is to create a few commands to spawn mobs, I know this already exists, but I wanted to try something simple for my first project.  I'll try to run it in java 8, hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: Did you fix it ?